# Unexpected token `switch` in switch statement React

Tags: reactjs, switch-statement

I am getting the Unexpected token `switch` error from the following code:

```
const bodyelements = () => (
    body.map(item => (
      switch (item?.typename) {
        case 'ArticleBodyText':
          return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item?.primary?.[0].text }} />
        case 'ArticleBodyImage':
          return <ArticleBodyImage item={item} />
        default:
          break;
      )}
  )
```

I already tried to look the error up on stackoverflow, but the fixes I saw didn't apply to my code. Does somebody know what's wrong?

EDIT:

I changed it to this

```
const bodyelements = () => {
    body.map(item => (
      switch (item?.__typename) {
        case 'ArticleBodyText':
          return <TextBlock dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item?.primary?.[0].text }} />
          break;
        case 'ArticleBodyImage':
          return <ArticleBodyImage item={item} />
          break;
        default:
          break;
      )}
      }
```

But I am still getting the same error

Comment: If you use `() => ()` function syntax, you can only place values in the return part. Use `() => {}` to be able to write code such as `switch` in the return part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short function syntax have two alternatives:

1. One that uses an expression and returns its result:

   ```
   () => ( some_expression_with_a_result )
   ```
2. One that uses a block for one or more statements:

   ```
   () => { statement1; statement2 }
   ```

`switch` is a statement, so you need to use the block variant.

Answer (score 0):

You have these issues in your code

- Each switch case must return something if you are rendering.
- Your switch statement should be enclosed in block quotes.
- You should add return statement for items in map.

Try this

```html
const bodyelements = () => {
    return ['ArticleBodyText', 'ArticleBodyImage'].map(item => {
        switch (item) {
            case 'ArticleBodyText':
                return <div>1</div>;
            case 'ArticleBodyImage':
                return <div>2</div>;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    })
}
```